# anyway to install mvccontrib.testhelper with nuget

Tags: mvccontrib, nuget, mvccontrib-testhelper

I have installed mvccontrib using nuget with the usual install-package mvccontrib, but i notice there is no testhelper there. Is there some other way or flag that i have to use to install it.

Trying install-package mvccontrib.testhelper doesn't work...

Any ideas gladly received

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the nuget gallery http://nuget.org to search for packages. 
http://nuget.org/packages?q=MvcContrib&sortOrder=package-download-count

I only see the ci build of the testhelper on nuget. You might want to contact the owner of mvccontrib on getting the official package on nuget.

Comment: Looks like there was a [bug](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/workitem/7103) filed on this and several packages are available (for the CI builds). E.g. "install-package MvcContrib.Mvc3.TestHelper-ci".